# How can I get a Memory Crystal Lode or Memory Crystal II Lode?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

With the Hall of Rites added I need Memory Crystal Lode and Memory Crystal II Lode to get the Memory Crystals for the characters they are available for. I have not seen this item yet. How would I go about getting one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're usually offered by events. I horde mine unless there's a hero I feel like I just have to have. I've seen events that Memory Crystal Lodes could be found in only twice this year, although I got a few from each.

Basically, make sure to check event rewards, especially for non-specific events (rather than, say, the new Vincent event, which awards FFVII characters and memory crystals, watch for events like Anniversary celebrations and seasonal festivals), and play through the ones that offer MC Lodes!

(it helps to have a "main" party capable of clearing the higher level dungeons in those events - I used to keep a lot of my characters the same level and could never get to the end of event dungeons, but now I have a set of five who've broken the level cap I use to grab limited-time rewards like Memory Crystal Lodes and Souls of Heroes.)

note:  yes, I only slightly edited my answer from your other question, but the items you're asking about almost always come from the same events, so the same information applied.  SE prefers multiple questions to one merged one, so it's more appropriate to give a nearly-identical answer than to ask you to edit the questions together.

Comment: Yea I would have preferred them as one question as well. But those are the rules :/

Comment: Technically, since they have the same answer, they could be one question. But you couldn't know that until you knew the answers...

Comment: I also just noticed again you can (for now at least) purchase lodes with Gysahl Greens.